# Count unique distinct values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unique, excel-2016

I would like to count how many unique distinct scopes a certain country has in the table. The country may appear more than once in the table, in this case it has a different id (row B=”note”). The country may have more than one scope.

In the example below there should be a number 4, because France with id 483, 484, 485 and 486 has scope 9001 (i.e. 4 times).

I have tried to use the following formula, but I think I am stuck…

`=SUM(IF(("France"=Findings!E2098:E5000)*("9001"=Findings!H2098:H5000), 1/COUNTIFS(Findings!E2098:E5000, "France", Findings!B2098:B5000, Findings!B2098:B5000, Findings!H2098:H5000, "9001")), 0)`
[image]

Comment: What version of Excel have you got?

Comment: @JvdV Excel 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way of counting using `FREQUENCY`:

[image]

Formula in `F1`:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(D2:D15=9001,IF(C2:C15="France",MATCH(A2:A15,A2:A15,0))),ROW(A2:A15)-ROW(A2)+1)>0))
```

Enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: YEAAHHH! Exactly, my dear JvdV! This is what I need! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

As per below screenshot please try below formula. You have to adjust ranges for your data setup.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$10="France")*($D$2:$D$10=9001)*(1/COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$10,$C$2:$C$10,$A$2:$A$10,$A$2:$A$10,$D$2:$D$10,$D$2:$D$10)))
```

[image]

If you have `Excel365` then you can simplify using-

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A10,(C2:C10="France")*(D2:D10=9001))))
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! 
I have just asjusted the ranges form y data setup, however I receive an error message: 
#DIV/0!
Have I done smth wrong? 

`=SUMPRODUCT(($E$2098:$E$5000="France")*($H$2098:$H$5000=9001)*(1/COUNTIFS($E$2098:$E$5000;$E$2098:$E$5000;$B$2098:$B$5000;$B$2098:$B$5000;$H$2098:$H$5000;$H$2098:$H$5000))) `